# Does linearly independent imply all elements are orthogonal?

Tags: linear-algebra

As the title states, if you have $A\subset V$ where $V$ is a vector space over an arbitrary field, does $A$ being linearly independent imply that the elements of $A$ are orthogonal?

Comment: Hmm, how do you define orthogonality in a general vector space over an arbitrary field?

Comment: Given any linearly independent set of vectors on a finite dimension vector space, you can *define* a dot product on the space so that the vectors in the set are orthogonal. But in general, there isn't a single definition of orthogonal on a vector space - a vector space without a dot product does not have a notion of orthogonal.

Comment: Even in $\mathbb{R}^n$ with the Euclidean inner product, this is not true; take $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $(1,0),(1,1)$.

Comment: The converse is not true either.  In $\mathbb{F}_2^2$, $(1,1)$ and $(1,1)$ are orthogonal under the usual inner product, but they are linearly dependent.

Comment: @Ian In that case, would it be true to say that bases need not be orthogonal? If that is true, would it be correct to say that for an n-tuple space, there exists an n x n matrix of elementary row operations that can convert any basis into an orthogonal one? What about an n x m matrix space?

Comment: Bases need not be orthogonal, that's correct. As for orthogonalization, look up Gram-Schmidt.

Comment: @Batominovski true, but the converse IS true if your inner-product is positive definite, like people usually require.

Comment: @Johan Claes.  But how do you define positive-definiteness on an arbitrary field, as stated in the OP's problem statement?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It is not true. It is simple to find an example in $\mathbb{R}^2$ with the usual inner product: take $v=(1,0)$ and $u=(1,1)$, they are linearly independent but not orthogonal.

Comment: Indeed, any two vectors in $\Bbb R^2$ that are not in the same (or opposite) direction, no matter how small the angle between them.